# Filtering String based on a format

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of Strings and I want to filter them out based on either the pattern **parta-partb-partc or parta-partb-no-partc**. The no could be any positive integer while the other parts of the string are fixed.

```
For example

parta-partb-partc
parta-partb-1-partc
parta-partb-1xyz-partc
parta-partb-123-partc
parta-partb-abc-partc
```

After filtering by a regular expression my list should be

```
parta-partb-partc
parta-partb-1-partc
parta-partb-123-partc
```

My question is how do I write a regular expression combing both the conditions?

Comment: I am not sure how to write the regular expression to combine both the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String#matches` with the following regex pattern:

```
parta-partb-(?:\d+-)?partc
```

Sample script:

```
String input = "parta-partb-1-partc";
if (input.matches("parta-partb-(?:\\d+-)?partc")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

Note that `String#matches` by default will apply the pattern to the entire input string, so no starting/ending anchors are required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it doesn't seem to match the string parta-partb-partc. Also will the "\" in input.matches need escaping?

Comment: @dividedbyzero You are correct, I have updated my answer, thanks.